# jquery each as 'named function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, each

I want to use this syntax

```
var x = function() {
      //do something here
}
```

on an each function

```
$("#firstname, #surname").each(function( index ) {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    errors += 1;
    }
});
```

Is this possible, and what is this called (I called it 'named functions' is this right)?

**EDIT**

So something like this

```
var errors = $("#firstname, #surname").each(function( index ) {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    errors += 1;
  }
  return errors;
});

console.log("you have".errors()."errors");
```

Comment: You mean like: `().each(x)`?

Comment: In the first code segment, `x` is a **variable** referring to an **anonymous fuction**. In the second segment, you're simply passing an anonymous function to be used by the `each()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a function is used like this:

```
$(...).each(function() {
   ...
});
```

it is called an [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) or lambda function.

I have never heard the term "named function" but I guess you could call it like that, when you assign the function to a variable.

[`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) returns like nearly all jQuery-methods the first argument, which is the equivalent of `$("#firstname, #surname")`. This is very important to understand as it is one of the key-mechanics of jQuery and enables you to do cool stuff like method chaining, e.g. `$("#firstname, #surname").each(do something).each(do even more)`. That means, you can not return your errors in the `each` method and pass it to a variable outside of the construct.

You could increment a global variable:

```
var errors = 0
$("#firstname, #surname").map(function() {
   if ($(this).val() == '') {
      errors++
   }
});

console.log("you have" + errors + "errors");
```

Note the string concatenator `+`, not `.`.

Another idea might be to use the [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method, which indeed enables you to return a value:

```
var errors = $("#firstname, #surname").map(function() {
   if ($(this).val() == '') {
      return 1
   }
   return 0
});
```

But this would just leave you with an array of `1` and `0` elements which is more or less the same with what you have started. You would need to add another loop to summ the elements together.

Finally let's get to the [`jQuery.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, which should be just what you need:

```
var errors = $("#firstname, #surname").filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() == "";
}).length;

console.log("you have " + errors + " errors");
```

Filter will return only those elements where the passed function returned a truthy value, so in this case, all elements that had an empty value. You could not only count the elements but immediately highlight the empty form elements:

```
var errors = $("#firstname, #surname").filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() == "";
}).css("background-color", "red").length;

console.log("you have " + errors + " errors");
```

Comment: Please note I made some updates to the examples, most importantly I accidentally used  `.count` instead of `.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example has a simple solution because you can just use filter and observe the length of the result, but in general, `reduce()` is the operation to use when you want to aggregate something about all of the items in a collection into a single value.

[jQuery doesn't have a `reduce()` method](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1886), but [ES5 arrays do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), so you could use it like this:

```
var errorCount = $("#firstname, #surname").toArray().reduce(function(count, item) {
    return count + ($(item).val() === '' ? 1 : 0);
}, 0);
```

As already stated, `filter()` is what you should be using here, but hopefully this will help you at some point in the future.